# Python - Printing values from a c++ DLL error

Tags: python, c++, io, runtime-error, ioerror

I have a short snippet of python code which calls a C++ DLL. The DLL function takes in a pointer to a table of 6 doubles (for output), and a table of strings for input.

```
myDll.get_results.argtypes = [ ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 6), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char*100) ]

results = (ctypes.c_double * 6)()
myDLL.get_results(ctypes.byref(results), input_string)
```

I then print out the results:

```
for r in results:
    print r
```

And this works fine most of the time. Once in a while though, I get the following error, which happens when printing the values. It happens randomly, i.e. it can happen after printing the first value or the last.

```
0.0
0.1
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Documents\test.py", line 109, in <module>    execute()
  File "d:\Documents\test.py", line 45, in execute
    print(f)IOError: [Errno 0] Error
PS D:\Documents>
```

It also (seems to) never happens if I set a breakpoint before printing. I tried putting a sleep of 1 second before printing and that doesn't help, the error still happens.

On the C++ side of things, my function looks like this:

```
RESULT_API void get_results(double res[6], char c[][100]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            res[i] = (double)i*0.1;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your issue but one thing i noticed at the first look was that the second parameter of `get_results` function is of type `char **` but in `myDll.get_results.argtypes` you specify `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char*100)` as argument which looks like a `char*` doesn't it ?

Comment: Thanks,  I'll make sure to correct that. As you said it doesn't really do anything for the print error, since I'm not even using the second param

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have miss-diagnosed the issue. The problem is with IO in VSCode, not with my code:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36630

It is a known issue, and can happen with any consecutive print to the console. Not related at all to the DLL!
Fix is already on its way.